# How comes std::invoke does not handle function overloads

Tags: c++

I'm experimenting with some C++17 features and came across std::invoke. I then tried this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f(int i) { std::cout << "fa "; }
void f(float f) { std::cout << "fb "; }

int main() {
    f(0.f);
    std::invoke(f, 0.f);
}
```

and I'm getting these errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:23: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, float)'
 std::invoke(f, 0.f);

In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
c:/compilers/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/functional:77:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::invoke_result_t<_Callable, _Args ...> std::invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
 invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
 ^~~~~~

c:/compilers/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/functional:77:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:9:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
 std::invoke(f, 0.f);
                   ^
```

I'm not a cpp pro, this is just for experimenting purposes. I probably won't ever use it in a case like this, but why is it not able to resolve the function overload ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `invoke`. You are using the name `f` without specifying which `f` you mean. The way around it is a bit ugly: `static_cast<void(*)(int)>(f)`.

Comment: Thanks, weird, like I responded in the answer, I thought it would be more flexible. That's a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might even simplify your example to:

```
void f(int i) {}
void f(float f) {}

template<typename F>
void foo(F) {}

foo(f); // compilation error here
```

The reason for compilation error is quite simple: compiler does not know which `f` overload you are going to use.

In order to avoid such error, you should help the compiler to deduce the right type doing the explicit cast using `static_cast`:

```
foo(static_cast<void(*)(float)>(f));
```

The same is true for `std::invoke`:

```
std::invoke(static_cast<void(*)(float)>(f), 0.f);
```

Comment: At the first glance I thought that since invoke uses a template to deduce the function type, it would deduce the signature based on the given function.

Answer (score 2):

Edgar's answer explains why this gives you an error, but there is a nicer way to work around it than having to use a cast, which requires you to provide the exact function signature (which might not be known).

It involves "lifting" the overload resolution into a templated `operator()` function:

```
std::invoke([](auto&&... xs) -> decltype(auto) { return f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); }, 0.f);
```

Now this looks wordy, and it is, but you can make it more palatable with a macro:

```
#define LIFT(F) \
    ([](auto&&... xs) -> decltype(auto) { \
        return F(::std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); \
    })

std::invoke(LIFT(f), 0.f);
```

Comment: Could just use a macro for that cast too though :)

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks for the input. I was just writing a long comment with some questions and I think I understood why while writing it. My assumption: this lifting wraps a given function pointer around a functor. It works that way because it's a type instance (anonymous struct) and not a raw (function) pointer. Both of `f` functions have a different symbol at compile time eg `f_int` `f_float`. Now when I trype `invoke(f, ...)`  it does not know if I'm referring to `f_int` or `f_float` even though in the editor the symbols are the same (`f`). Is it right ? Sorry for trying that hard btw

Comment: @Riptide When you write `std::invoke(f, 0.f)` the compiler has to try and work out what `f` overload you want the function pointer to, but because this parameter of `invoke` is a deduced template parameter it can't decide and you get an ambiguity; it doesn't look inside `invoke` to see how its used. Now with the `LIFT` macro we are passing an actual object. The "magic" is that the object can be called with anything because it has a templated `operator()`. Because overload resolution now happens inside `operator()` and not during template argument deduction, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Ohh that makes perfect sense, the last sentence made me realize it ("during template argument deduction"), I'm happy and grateful to learn so much from everyone here.