# Auto deduce type of function in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, generic-programming

I have simple `map` implementation and simple `id` (identity):

```
template <typename T>
T map(const T& x, std::function<decltype(x[0])(decltype(x[0]))> f) {
    T res(x.size());
    auto res_iter = begin(res);
    for (auto i(begin(x)); i < end(x); ++i) {
        *res_iter++ = f(*i);
    }
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
T id(T& x) {return x;}
```

and when I call is as

```
vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
map(a, id<const int>);
```

it works, but I want call it without type specification, like this:

```
map(a, id);
```

and when I do it, I get error:

```
error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'id' based on conversion to type 'std::function<const int&(const int&)>'
 map(a, id);
          ^
```

How can I resolve it and why can't compiler deduce type of `id` from its context in `map` when error contains right bounded type?

Comment: I'm going to turn the useful part from my earlier non-answer into a comment: it's generally better to have a plain template parameter for function inputs (and documentation of the type signature), instead of `std::function`.  It doesn't fix the problem, but something like: `template<typename T, typename F>
T map(const T& x, F&& f)`.  Something like std::function would be great here _if_ C++ type inference went a little farther.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a C++14 compliant environment, there is a very clean way to do this. Instead of using std::function and a templated class, use an unconstrained forwarding reference and a generic lambda as follows:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T,typename F>
T map(const T& x, F &&f) {
  T res(x.size());
  auto res_iter = begin(res);
  for (auto i(begin(x)); i < end(x); ++i) {
    *res_iter++ = f(*i);
  }
  return res;
}

auto id = [](auto x) { return x;};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  auto v2 = map(v, id);
}
```

In C++11, you would have to replace the generic lambda with a functor whose operator() is a templated method, as follows:

```
struct {
  template<typename T>
  T operator()(T x) const
  {
    return x;
  }
} id;
```

In C++98 syntax you will not be able to use the forwarding reference, so you will have to consider copying and functor mutability issues.

Comment: Can templates be used in this version of `map` some way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can templates be used?" Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `id` is not a function. It's a function template !

It means that `id` is a template that generates function such as `id<const int>` but is not really a function by itself.

At runtime there is no `id`, only instance of function created by `id`.

Comment: But when compiler see call of `id` with `int` as parameter, shouldn't it create instance of `id<int>`?

Comment: What's the solution, then?

Comment: The solution is to use `id<const int>`, a `static_cast` or a [LIFT macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506294/2491746).

Comment: Question is "how can I ...", answer is "it's because ..." -1

Comment: @Slava: fair enough

Comment: @Slava: Well, question is how and why so I'm half way good :D